# Reading form controls inside nodejs Express server side

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to access the entire form data in Nodejs Express server side so that i can get the value of "value" property of the checkboxes.

I have the below set up in my server side,but i am getting error req.body undefined when i try to print the contents of request.

checkbox Controls inside the form is dynamically created and number of checkboxes inside the form will very from scenario to scenario

Setup in my server

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
// in latest body-parser use like below.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/post',function(req,response){
    console.log(req.body) //you will get your data in this as object.
 })
```

Client side

```
<div class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
<form action="#" name ="submitform">
    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews1" name="subscribe1" 
     value="1">
    <label for="subscribeNews1">Subscribe to newsletter1?</label>

    <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews1" name="subscribe1" 
     value="1">
    <label for="subscribeNews1">Subscribe to newsletter1?</label>

     <input type="checkbox" id="subscribeNews2" name="subscribe2" 
     value="1">
    <label for="subscribeNews2">Subscribe to newsletter2?</label>
</form>
```

Can some one suggest what is the reason for this error and how can i resolve it?
I have gone through similar threads and none of the solution is helping me in resolving my issue.

Comment: `<form action="/post" name ="submitform" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

Your form is missing:

```
 method="post"
```

To post to /post you'd use the following:

```
<form action="/post" method="post" name="submitform">
```